# chrome not show original variable names when debugging a bundled javascript file build by webpack

Tags: webpack

I use this code to config webpack 5:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```

and this is my index.js code,

```
const bar=require('./bar.js');
let a=1
console.log(a)
bar();
```

When debugging, I can not access the variable named "a"
[image]

Is this a bug of webpack?
I remember its not like this when I worked with an earlier verison of webpack years ago.

[image]

Comment: If you look at the compiled bundle you'll see why - my guess is that during bundling webpack has inlined the value of `a` and removed the `a` variable declaration altogether, as hinted at on the left-hand-side under Scope > Local.

Comment: @sdgluck Thanks for your reply. Let me check the bundled file.

Comment: @sdgluck  You are right! Thanks! So is it there is no way to use the original variable names to debug a webpacked file even when the source map files are provided ? I remember I can use the original variable names to debug years ago.

Comment: Yes, you can have it bundle in such a way that identifiers are not mangled - take a look at options available on the [`optimization` field](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/), eg. `minimize: false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shamelessly copied from (my own) comments...

If you look at the compiled bundle you'll see why - my guess is that during bundling webpack has inlined the value of `a` and removed the `a` variable declaration altogether, as hinted at on the left-hand-side of your image, under `Scope > Local`.

You can have webpack bundle in such a way that identifiers are not mangled - take a look at options available on the [`optimization` field](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/), eg. `minimize: false`.